# Collision Problems

Tags: eevee-render-engine, cloth-simulation

Currently I'm working on a cloth simulated shirt, and everything seems to be colliding fine with the upper body, but the when I added collision to the pants, the shirt started getting sucked into the pants in all of my renders and bakes. I've fiddled around with the settings, but I can't get it to work right. Does anyone know what's causing it or how to fix? Any info would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
JLK9kid
[image]
[image: Screenshot of render that shows the tucked in shirt]

Comment: Hi, first of all, i think you have much too much geometry for your cloth simulation. So i would reduce that. Also there is a weird "edge" [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVTdy.png in your cloth, i would remove that. I would uncheck "single side" from your collision object, then it looks already better

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I’ll look into the changes you suggested. However, the weird edge you found is supposed to be where the triangle is, which is pretty important to design of the character. I don’t know if that’s the best way to do it, but I found that it was working for me.

Comment: I just tried it, and unchecking single-sided seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the help!